# append list elements "random-without repeat" to multiple html files

Tags: python, html, random, beautifulsoup, href

I'm trying to replace `href` `url` with a result value using `regex`, I also tried `Beautifulsoup` module but no success.keep getting one and the same one url in all html files

```
class RandomChoiceNoImmediateRepeat(object):
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst
        self.last = None
    def choice(self):
        if self.last is None:
            self.last = random.choice(self.lst)
            return self.last
        else:
            nxt = random.choice(self.lst)
            # make a new choice as long as it's equal to the last.
            while nxt == self.last:   
                nxt = random.choice(self.lst)
            # Replace the last and return the choice
            self.last = nxt
            return nxt

for filename in glob.glob('/docs/*.txt'):
    file_metadata = { 'name': 'file.txt', 'mimeType': '*/*' }
    media = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype='*/*', resumable=True)
    file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
    link = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' + file.get('id')
    linkd = []
    linkd.append(link)
    for filename in glob.glob('/docs/htmlz/*.html'):
        with open(filename, "r") as html_file:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file,'html.parser')
            for anchor in soup.findAll("a", attrs={ "class" : "downloadme" }):
                gen = RandomChoiceNoImmediateRepeat(linkd)
                i = gen.choice()
                anchor['href'] = str(i)
                with open(filename, "w") as html_file:
                    html_file.write(str(soup))
                    html_file.close()
```

Comment: re.sub requires string. so convert to 'str(anchor)' and see if it works.

Comment: i did it not working, the error disappear but no result url of the href does not change

Answer (score 0):

First of all, root-cause is the `re.sub` requires string or bytes-like object but you provide other type.

**EDIT:**

I have created an example how you can access the elements of `bs4.element.ResultSet` type.

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<tr class="hello">first_elem</tr><tr>second_elem</tr>', "html.parser")
trs = soup.find_all("tr")
print("Content: {}  -->  Type: {}".format(trs, type(trs)))
print("Content: {}  -->  Type: {}".format(trs[0], type(trs[0])))
print("Content: {}  -->  Type: {}".format(trs[0]["class"], type(trs[0]["class"])))
print("Content: {}  -->  Type: {}".format(trs[0]["class"][0], type(trs[0]["class"][0])))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 ci/common/python_utils/test_file.py 
Content: [<tr class="hello">first_elem</tr>, <tr>second_elem</tr>]  -->  Type: <class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
Content: <tr class="hello">first_elem</tr>  -->  Type: <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
Content: ['hello']  -->  Type: <class 'list'>
Content: hello  -->  Type: <class 'str'>
```

As you can see above the `.findAll` provides a `bs4.element.ResultSet` type which contains `bs4.element.Tag` elements. If you select the tag, you get a list, like: `['hello']` and you have to use the correct index like: `[0]` and you will get the string type variable (As you can see in the last line of output).

Comment: i get always error this time issue with key 

"" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newpost.py", line 95, in <module>
    re.sub("https\:\/\/drive.google.com\/uc\?export\=download&id\=(.*)", r'\g<1>'+e, anchor[0])
  File "/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 971, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 0

 ""

Comment: I see! You should print the `anchor` variable and check the content and how you can access the elements. The problem is that the `anchor` "container" does not have `0` key.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope it can help to solve your problem. Let me know if you need more support.

Comment: i did not succeed in this i tried another method but i have an issue if you can help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59599669/assign-lines-from-txt-file-to-html-files-regex-bs4