# assign lines from txt file to html files regex bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i need to assign a line from a text file containing 7 lines every line with a url, these urls should be replacing href url in 7 html files

the issue is that i had the same value or the same url in all html files on all seven html files here is my code:

```
regex = re.compile("https\:\/\/(.*)\n")
with open("urls.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            result = regex.search(line)
            for filename in glob.glob('/htmlz/*.html'):
                with open(filename, "r") as html_file:
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file,'html.parser')
                    for anchor in soup.findAll("a", attrs={ "class" : "link" }):
                        anchor['href'] = result.group(0)
                        with open(filename, "w") as htmlfile2:
                            htmlfile2.write(str(soup))
```

Comment: `anchor['href'] = result.group(0)`

Comment: thank you it helped me to get the right url 
```
<a class="downloadme" href="/uc?export=download&id=15PK24b6vxH4s_C9ytpwgfR88Ju0HFMFz" style="display: none;"> Get your file</a>

```
but i get the same url in all seven 7 html files

Comment: do you have someting more in lines except urls? Do you need regex for this? Maybe you should first get files and later uses `zip(all_urls, all_files)` to group url with file.

Comment: i only have urls in this text file nothing else i use regex just to select them one by one to assign them to href anchor html